# Code takes 300 index array and makes it 47 million indexes long (np.log10)

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code which is supposed to just do simple calculations on a numpy array output from a function I made. The function produces a 314 index long numpy array with all values greater than zero. The output however ends up being 47,100,000 indexes long. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the code, is it something to do with numpy's log10 function?

```
rho_c = 150000 #kg/m3
P = 26.5*(10**15)
G = 6.67*(10**-11)
r = 696340000

n=1

xi,theta=lane_emden(n)
theta = theta[:-1]
xi = xi[:-1]
print(theta)
print(np.shape(theta))
rho_log = np.log10(theta*rho_c)
print(np.shape(rho_log))
m = 4*np.pi*(r**2)*(10**rho_log)
print(np.shape(m))
p_log = np.log10(-G*m*rho_c/(r**2))
print(np.shape(p_log))
```

I'm hoping that the outputs `rho_log`, `m`, `p_log`, will also be 314 indexes long, and I'm not sure what is causing it.

Comment: Make sure the `lane_emden` function initially returns arrays of length 314. Ensure that the `lane_emden` function doesn't return any compound structure (like a list of arrays) that could mislead the shape outputs. One troubleshooting step is to print the shapes right after receiving them from the `lane_emden` function.

Comment: You printed the shapes here, but you didn't show us the values.  The problem is almost certainly that `lane_emden` is not returning what you think it is.

Comment: I think I figured it out, `theta*rho_c` isn't multiplying all of the values in the theta array, its trying to make a new array which is `rho_c` number of the entire `theta` array.